# How to match the beginning of a line in leex?

Tags: regex, erlang, leex

According to [the leex documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html)

> ^    Matches the beginning of a string.

But when I try to use it in a pattern such as `^[^\s\t-:]+[^:].*$` I get this error: `bad regexp 'illegal character ^'`

Is there a better way to match the begging of a line | string in leex?

Comment: This may or may not be related to your issue but your first character set is likely not what you want. `[^\s\t-:]` means "**Neither** A space character *or* any character in the **range** from tab character to `:`" It will use the ascii character set when creating this range.

Comment: thanks @iismathwizard, that is true and a mistake; but chaning to `[^\s\t:-]` still produces the same error :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the [documentation page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html) you find this note:

> Anchoring a regular expression with ^ and $ is not implemented in the
>   current version of Leex and just generates a parse error.

Which seems to mean you can't use `^` and `$` with a regexp in between like you do.

If you know the strings end with a specific character (like `\n`) I assume you can replace the `$` with that char delimiter instead.

Comment: This will be fixed in a future major release. :-)

Comment: Wow, is there any workaround for this? For example, how would one parse python code (whitespace indentation matters at the beginning of line)?

Answer (score 2):

(Yes, leex does not support an anchor token '^'). You need to use \A anchor instead